# an error on connectionstring

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

there is an error red underline on (connectionString)which said that the name'ConnectionString' does not exist in the current context. 
Do i need to declare sth before i use the using statement?

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=baaa;Initial Catalog=InventorySystem;Integrated Security=True") ; 

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT product.P_ID, Product.P_Name,Product.Leadtime, Product.SafetyStockamount," +
        "Monthlysales.Month, Monthlysales.totalsalesamount, (totalsalesamount/30) as Averagedailysales, ((totalsalesamount/30) * Leadtime + SafetyStockamount) as reorderpoint " +
        "FROM Product, Monthlysales " +
        "where Product.P_ID = Monthlysales.P_ID AND Product.P_ID =@P_ID AND Monthlysales.Month =@Month ", connection))
        {

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("P_ID", pid));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Month", Startmonth));
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            // now you have the data in Dataset ds
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `using` statement, you want to get value of `connectionString`. But there is not any variable.

Change

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=baaa;Initial Catalog=InventorySystem;Integrated Security=True") ;
```

to

```
string connectionString= "Data Source=baaa;Initial Catalog=InventorySystem;Integrated Security=True";
```

---

Also, you have not ending bracket in `using` statement.

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
```

Comment: but i got another error also in this code "where Product.P_ID = Monthlysales.P_ID AND Product.P_ID =@P_ID AND Monthlysales.Month =@Month ", connection)). There is an error in 'connection))' part. do you know what happened?

Comment: @user3600939 What is the exact exception Message? Please debug and see the message.

Comment: Line 23:         using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
Line 24:         {
Line 25:             connection.Open();
Line 26: 
Line 27:             using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(   that is the error when i run the  page

Comment: @user3600939 Close browser. Rebuild your project. Run it with `F5` and tell us the exception message please.

Comment: C:\Users\baa\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite11 - Copy - Copy\Manager\Forecastreorderpoint.aspx.cs(25,30): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected
C:\Users\baa\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite11 - Copy - Copy\Manager\Forecastreorderpoint.aspx.cs(40,14): error CS1514: { expected
those message is referring to Line 25: connection.Open();

Comment: @user3600939 This is not the exception message. This is compile time error. I am speaking about runtime errors.

Comment: @user3600939 You can tell me in which line red underline is occured?

Comment: how i can find the runtime errors? im new in this field.  in 'connection.Open();' the semicolon has a blue underline on it.

Comment: @user3600939 Have you add ending bracket  to your using statement?

Comment: ooooo farhad,ya i havent. i just realized it now. i solved it already. thank you so much for ur help

Comment: @user3600939 I am very glad now. You can Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. And, I will gain my `15` reputation.

Comment: heii, do u know how i can i continue this code so i can show the reorder point result in label? actually in my interface i have pid option, month options, button and label . so if the user choose pid 1, month 2 (february) then the result will come out in the label.

Comment: @user3600939 Sorry, but we can't help further. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints.

Answer (score 0):

If you are completely sure about your connectionString, user this code :

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=baaa;Initial Catalog=InventorySystem;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT product.P_ID, Product.P_Name,Product.Leadtime, Product.SafetyStockamount," +
        "Monthlysales.Month, Monthlysales.totalsalesamount, (totalsalesamount/30) as Averagedailysales, ((totalsalesamount/30) * Leadtime + SafetyStockamount) as reorderpoint " +
        "FROM Product, Monthlysales " +
        "where Product.P_ID = Monthlysales.P_ID AND Product.P_ID =@P_ID AND Monthlysales.Month =@Month ", connection))
        {

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("P_ID", pid));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Month", Startmonth));
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As your code

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=baaa;Initial Catalog=InventorySystem;Integrated Security=True") ;
```

You are making instance of connection that is not connectionstring. make it `String connectionString` and pass them as parameter to SqlConnection.